How would the login/registration window be designed if users were given the option to proceed without logging in initially?
In this case, it concerns booking courses. To book a course, creating a participant profile is required. Once the user clicks on "Create Participant Profile", the login window is triggered, and the user is prompted to log in/register.
However, the user also has the option to proceed with creating the participant profile without logging in/registering initially. Registration/login is mandatory at the latest for the checkout process.
So, how could such a login window look?
Would something like this work? The same applies to the mobile version.


Do users always get to the checkout eventually? In that case the suggestion that an account is not needed is misleading.

You're right. The goal is of course the checkout process. Another consideration is to give users the opportunity to access participants using a code without having to create an account. In this case, the customer cannot book a course; this is only possible with an account.

In that case, rename the bottom button to "Create account later".

If an account is required but not required right now, could you change the label to "Log in later"? Maybe some microcopy that explains that they must before checkout.
What is the difference between an account and a participant profile?
We use a similar design, and we even added an "or" to the dividing line:


The distinction between an account and a participant profile lies in where the data is stored. Participant profile data is saved in a session within the user's browser, while account information is stored in our database. Upon signing in, the data from the participant session will be transferred to our database as well.

Are you sure (have it easily explained somewhere) that users get this distinction? If I did not want to enter personal details and did not create an account for that reason, I would wonder whether I would create a "profile" with personal details.
